# Error while compiling latest source of Files

Tags: pantheon-files, vala

I get two errors while compiling the latest source of Files.

```
error: The name `with_total_usage' does not exist in the context of `Granite.Widgets.StorageBar'
            storagebar = new Granite.Widgets.StorageBar.with_total_usage (fs_capacity, fs_used);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And

```
 error: The name `FILES' does not exist in the context of `Granite.Widgets.StorageBar.ItemDescription'
        storagebar.update_block_size (Granite.Widgets.StorageBar.ItemDescription.FILES, size);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But when compiling the 0.2.x version it builds perfectly.

Also, as a side question, why can't I compile `main.vala` with `valac main.vala` whitout failing because it can't find Marlin?

Comment: main.vala is not an independent program - there are a lot of dependencies which valac needs to be able to find.  It is intended that you use cmake to build Files (after installing all the necessary -dev packages).

Answer (score 1):

Those two errors are pretty self-explanatory.  `Granite.Widgets.StorageBar.with_total_usage` and `Granite.Widgets.StorageBar.ItemDescription.FILES` don't exist in the version of granite you have installed.  You probably need a newer version of granite (quite possibly from git or whatever they use for revision control, if that's where you got files).